# How can i downgrade my compile version?

Tags: android, compilation, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to work with API 23 to get more device compatibility.
I'm trying to set '23' on my build.gradle file but when i do the Sync i got some error with the "debug/AndroidManifest".

Here's my **build.gradle** file:

Error shown on **debug\AndroidManifest**:

```
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="cloud.domore.domore"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/DoMoreTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="cloud.domore.domore.AuthenticationActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

What I have to modify to downgrande my compile and running API version?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post source code, such as `build.gradle`, as **text**, not as images. Also, in the future, please post the actual error, not just "some error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i downgrade my compile version?

There is no particular need to downgrade your `compileSdkVersion`. If anything, you might increase it to 27.

> I want to work with API 23 to get more device compatibility

You are already set up to work back to API Level 21 (`minSdkVersion 21`). `compileSdkVersion` has nothing to do with backwards compatibility.

> What I have to modify to downgrande my compile and running API version?

In your case, you do nothing, as you are already set to support API Level 21+ devices.

With respect to `compileSdkVersion` and `com.android.support` libraries:

- All standard `com.android.support` libraries that you are using need to have the same version (e.g., `27.0.2`)
- The `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` should be set to the same value, which is the major version of the library (e.g., `27`)

Comment: you are already using 23 version . You have already specified targetsdkversion to 23. If you arr getting some error then that's a different story. post your build.gradle file here